# Google Analytics Custom Metric counts more than once on a unique membership page. How can I fix it?

Tags: google-analytics, custom-variables

On Google Analytics I have this metric called Yeni Uyelik which counts new memberships. I expect this metric to count 1 for every unique page. However, in the report on some pages it counts up to 10 and GA reports show more memberships than database. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there a possibility that user can share/save or bookmark this page url ?

Comment: I mean if the link is session dependent or in simpler terms : will this link work if you copy paste it and try it on another browser ?

Comment: I tried to work the link on another browser and it returns "404 - File or directory not found."

Comment: can you provide a full url ? If this page has some important details which user needs to lookup after sometime from the time of transaction..and if your website allows the complete url to be accessible by the user later on....then there can be multiple new users for the same page

Comment: could you provide more details on this such as - how the metric is calculated?

Comment: The URL where you create new membership: http://m.kariyer.net/YeniAdayKayit.aspx

This is the page where custom metric runs:
http://m.kariyer.net/uyeliktamamlandi.aspx?refnumber=ZtaxQTb3vmxDLl+YanmX0g==!e!&email=VG2PmsoFzlS2nW4Ux1tydnKr4tKljVzd!e!&name=eZIgZ7oSvIfp2Bvm6GWmWA==!e!

screenchot of the successful membership page: http://hizliresim.com/LQrMrb

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your new user page is refreshable. This, with the addition that it automattically redirects you is probably causing the problem.

In user terms, I create an account, get to the new user page, and click on the button to get to now in my account. If I hit back on my browser, the new user  page loads again with the custom dimension 3 value of 1, and I am immediately redirected back to the account page. Its very likely that the high number of custom metric 3 is due to the fact that users keep trying to go back, and are push forward by the screen that has the custom dimension. This would then lead to the same page counting the custom metric multiple times, adding it  to the same count.

To overcome this you can create a cookie with the value of the refnumber query value on the pageview where the new account page occurs. Then you can create custom logic dictating that if the cookie value equals the query value, then the user has seen this screen before, and then to set the value of the Custom Metric to 0, else 1.